# A handy .BAT file to update a local Sybase SQL DB

Tags: batch-file, sybase

I need to make a change in my local Sybase DB quite often,
changing "version2" value to "10.0**76**" and sometimes to "10.0**80**".

If instead of opening the Interactive SQL tool, typing in DB's credentials each time, I could just run a "76.bat" or "80.bat" file, it would be very handy.

The query is:

```
UPDATE "trogxxx"."xxversion" SET "version2"=10.076 WHERE "version"='2002'
```

And credentials:

```
UserID: Trogxxx
Password: Trogxxx2018
ServerName: dem8
```

How would a .BAT file look like, in order to log in and run the update?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a basic bat file calling to isql on the command line and use the -i flag to indicate the SQL script containing the update statement which then gets called as an input file. You could prompt for the -U (username) and -P (password) options or hardcode as much as you want.

Syntax: isql -U username -P password -S server -i input_filename

This assumes your environment has sufficient settings for your normal Sybase client e.g. %SYBASE% etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Rich. So I've created two files:
"76.sql" containing:
`UPDATE "trogxxx"."xxversion" SET "version2"=10.076 WHERE "version"='2002'` and "76.bat" containing:
`isql -U Trogxxx -P Trogxxx2018 -S dem8 -i 76.sql`.
Then I run the "76.bat" and the DB doesn't seem to be changed.

Comment: You need to add a 'go' statement on a new line to execute SQL via isql (some SQL tools add this for you) then it should work fine for you.